# Python: How to show license text in msi installer generated from setup.py

Tags: python, installation, windows-installer, distutils

In setup.py the call to the setup function may look like this:

```
setup(name="my_package",
      version="1.0",
      packages = ['pack1', 'pack2'],
      license = "We're all mad here"
)
```

And I use the very nice feature to generate an msi installer:

```
python setup.py bdist_msi
```

Is there any way to get the license text "We're all mad here" to be displayed in the msi installer wizard?

thanks.

Comment: The author of bdist_msi is on SO, I believe the maintainer of distutils2 is too. There are bound to be folks around here who know their msi-fu enough to guide a Python developer. If you really want this to happen, follow the links, improve the question (add some results of what you tried) and you have a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimistic, detailed answer:  you [extend distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/extending.html), creating a new command based on [bdist_msi](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distutils2/src/0de7d5f4dae5/distutils2/command/bdist_msi.py#cl-84). You'll probably have to create a new [PyDialog](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distutils2/src/0de7d5f4dae5/distutils2/command/bdist_msi.py#cl-23) in (your equivalent to) [bdist_msi.add_ui](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distutils2/src/0de7d5f4dae5/distutils2/command/bdist_msi.py#cl-412). I think you'll have to add your dialog to [UI Sequences](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distutils2/src/0de7d5f4dae5/distutils2/command/bdist_msi.py#cl-444). The simplest dialog seems to be [Prepare Dialog](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distutils2/src/0de7d5f4dae5/distutils2/command/bdist_msi.py#cl-557). Knowing your way around [msilib](http://docs.python.org/library/msilib.html), its [Dialog](http://docs.python.org/library/msilib.html#msilib.Dialog) class and the references under "See also" there would certainly help.

Realistic answer: you don't, not without investing considerable energy in it. You use another installer mechanism, you edit the MSI, you figure out some trick involving .rtf files. But extending distutils is hard, extending bdist_msi is harder.

Comment: There's a quite comprehensive [sample](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d7ae948d9eee/Tools/msi/uisample.py) in Python's source code repo which you might use as a start. Also, [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) customizes bdist_msi, so you might also take a look at [what they're doing](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/src/04ca56e81816bda14de37bfe824f7fad93f353ee/cx_Freeze/windist.py?at=default).